# TypeScript: Root reducer type while using dynamic reducers

Tags: typescript, redux

Is there a way to get type checking for application state that is largely made using dynamic reducers? The [official documentation](https://rangle.io/blog/redux-typescripted) says that I should add types of the dynamic reducers to the root reducer type before injecting them. But that's no longer as modular as I would like it to be.

Right now my root reducer code looks something like this:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {auth} from './reducer-auth';
import {user} from './reducer-user';
import {ui} from './reducer-ui';

const appReducers = {
  auth,
  user,
  ui
};

export const appReducer = combineReducers(appReducers);

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof appReducer>;
```

I love this approach, but I need it to be more scalable, so I'm splitting a code into modules. My aim is to have modules as independent as possible:

**/global/register-module.ts:**

```
import {injectReducers} from 'global/reducers';
//...

export const registerModule = (id: string, module: IModule) => {
  if (module.reducers)
    injectReducers(module.reducers);
  // ...
};
```

**/auth/index.ts:**

```
/** @file Authentication module */

import {registerModule} from 'global/register-module';
import {reducers} from './reducers';
import {sagas} from './sagas';
import {routes} from './routes';

registerModule('auth', {
  reducers,
  sagas,
  routes
});
```

**/global/config/modules.ts**

```
/** @file Modules index */

import 'auth';
import 'user';
import 'ui';
// ...
```

It would be great to just import a module and don't have to care about any additional setup. If that's not possible, then I can accept it, but I'm not so excited about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's still best to have a type that documents every possible field that can exist in the root state.

See this excellent article from a Dropbox developer with details on how they would approach code-splitting with types:

https://www.matthewgerstman.com/tech/redux-code-split-typecheck/

(also, that page you linked is definitely *not* "the official docs" - it's a post from Rangle.  Useful, but not part of our actual docs, which are at https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting .)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that it's not official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to define application state type in the same file where I import the modules. This seems to be a decent solution to me.

```
/** @file Modules index */

import 'auth';
import {AuthState} from 'auth';

import 'user';
import {UserState} from 'user';

import 'ui';
import {UiState} from 'ui';

export interface AppState {
  auth: AuthState;
  user: UserState;
  ui: UiState;
}
```